# Caps lock works as left arrow

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have came to work and discovered that my CapsLock key is not working, but it is actually working as left arrow key. I have tested with PassMark Keyboard test, and if i press CapsLock, left arrow is being pressed, led is not working too.
When computer is loading, i can turn led on and off, but not in Windows.
A week ago i have remapped Caps+(jkl;) to arrow keys, so i need caps.
System is Windows 8.1

Comment: Now, with help of AutoHotkey i have mapped left arrow to do nothing, and leftarrow+(jkl;) work like arrows.
So it looks like Caps+(jkl;) works like arrows, and left arrow not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like someone spilled a cup of coffee on the keyboard or similar. You can try cleaning it. Another solution is to ask the person in charge of material to hand you a new keyboard and get rid of the old.